# can't open a vbproj under vs 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to open a “vbproj” file that was written in .net 2.0 under Visual Studio 2005.
The problem is that when I try to open it with VS 2005, the conversion wizard appears and asks me to convert that project.
Please any one has met this issue..?

I need your help

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Which version is it saying you should convert to? And are you double clicking on the .vbproj file or opening VS2005 first and using the IDE to open the .vbproj file?

Answer (score 0):

The vbproj metafile has to be from a previous version. If you open that file in a notepad text editor you can verify the version in there. You should covert regardless without any major issues. Just back up the source and the associated .vb files.

Comment: I have check and it is the correct version.. Thanks for your answer